# Do I need an ESTA to enter the US with the Victoria Clipper ferry?

Tags: usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, ferries

I am thinking of visiting Victoria, BC in Canada and then going to Seattle, WA in the US, with the [Victoria Clipper ferry](http://www.clippervacations.com/seattle-victoria-ferry/).

I am a national of a country under the Visa Waiver Program. I think that if I enter by air, I need to fill an ESTA form. If I enter by car, I don't need one, I can fill a form when crossing the border.

With the ferry, what is the procedure? Should I necessarily have an ESTA?

Comment: Anecdotally I have heard of people with an ESTA being able to enter with it by land/sea. After all, they can easily verify your participation in the program.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah last time I crossed the border by land they told me it makes the process faster if I apply for an esta. I was still curious if it was mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country,-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/%7E/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country,-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico),

> If you are a citizen of a country that participates in the Visa Waiver Program (VWP), and you enter the U.S. by land from Mexico or Canada, you are only required to complete the paper I-94W form at the land border crossing.  ESTA is currently required for air and cruise ship travel only.
>
> Note:  VWP citizens do not need an ESTA to travel on the ferries between Vancouver and Victoria, BC and Washington state.  **They are treated as a land border port.**